# C# - Auto refresh a ListView

Tags: c#

I have a `ListView` and the `ListView` data is taken from database.
Beside the `ListView` got a button to add the record.

if the button is pressed it will show a dialog

Code :

```
private void bAddStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    fAddStudent addStudent = new fAddStudent();
    addStudent.ShowDialog();
}
```

After add the record, the dialog will `close()` and show the ListView. 
But the `ListView` is not update the data.

Is there any way to make it **auto update**?

**Edit :** 
Here is how I add records :

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string studentID = tbStudentId.Text;
    string studentName = tbStudentName.Text;
    string gender = tbGender.Text;

    string connectionString = "Data Source=xxx\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestApplication;Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID=xxx;Password=xxx";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO student (student_id, student_name, student_gender) VALUES (@studentId, @studentname, @studentGender) ");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentId", studentID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentName", studentName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentGender", gender);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Code For showing `ListView` :

```
List<string> myListHeader = new List<string>(new string[] { "ID", "Name", "Gender" });
myListHeader.ForEach(name => lvStudent.Columns.Add(name));

SqlConnection UGIcon = new SqlConnection();
UGIcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxx\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestApplication;Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID=xxx\\user;Password=xxx";
UGIcon.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM student", UGIcon);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read()) {
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr[0].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(dr[1].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(dr[2].ToString());
    lvStudent.Items.Add(item);
}
```

**Note**

**'Add data' form is different with showing the `ListView` form, so I cannot access the `ListView` in the 'add data' form**

Comment: Show code, where you add a record

Comment: Where is the code where you are creating as well as loading the ListView..? hard to tell what you are doing or have done unless you post relevant code..

Comment: shouldn't your code be actually assigning the listview Text property try something like this 
`items[0].SubItems[1].Text = dr[0].ToString(); ,...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call databind() method every time you want your data to be refreshed.

From what I understood you a)show the data, b) add new record to database but new record is not shown. If this is the case just call DataBind() method and it should work.

Comment: Can you give me an example for databind?
I am new in C#, sorry

Comment: You are adding your data to the list view very inefficiently :(. There are better ways to do this. But in order to get this to work just encapsulate all your list view code into one separate method (FillListVIew() or something like that) and call that method every time you add new student to your database.

Comment: Couple notes:
"SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM student", UGIcon);" - always make sure you explicitly reference the columns you want to use instead of using *

Comment: "item.SubItems.Add(dr[2].ToString());" - always reference your columns by column name and not by position. What if your database changes? Your code may stop working. Try something like this item.SubItems.Add(dr["column_name"].ToString());

Comment: yeah, I want all the columns. btw, I've already created a method to fill the listView but I cannot call it from another form

Comment: how come you can not call it from another form..? you most certainly can if you are referencing that form properly ..

Answer (score 1):

You add the record to the table on SQL Server. Since your `ListView` is not bound, it will not update.

You can go the simpliest way and create a method which refresh `ListView`:

```
private void RefreshListView()
{
// clear ListView
lvStudent.Items.Clear();
List<string> myListHeader = new List<string>(new string[] { "ID", "Name", "Gender" });
myListHeader.ForEach(name => lvStudent.Columns.Add(name));

SqlConnection UGIcon = new SqlConnection();
UGIcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxx\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestApplication;   Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID=xxx\\user;Password=xxx";
UGIcon.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM student", UGIcon);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read()) {
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr[0].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(dr[1].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(dr[2].ToString());
    lvStudent.Items.Add(item); }
}
```

Call this method each time when you add a new record to the SQL Server table. It's a pretty unlikely to do like that. I recommend you to use [bindings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10008/Data-binding-a-ListView), but it's more complicated.